# Limit availability of an iOS app to one country

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I have an iOS app which has been approved and is available for download on appstore. Is it possible to make it available only in one country (e.g. say Canada)

Answer (score 10):

## For Newer iTunes Connect

Click on "Pricing and Availability", and then check the Availability section.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

in itunes connect in "right and pricing" section you can define in which countries your app is available[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to limit availability only to few developers too.

Comment: @user462455 what is the sense of app publishing for dev only in appstore? use provision profiles for that

Comment: This lets us do full end to end testing after approval, and fix server side issues. And we can flip the switch without having to wait for ~10-15 days for approval

Comment: @user462455 then you need to give your binary directly to devs and their devices should be in provision profile